# Spring error: no qualifying bean for reposiotry

Tags: spring

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error. Below are the details of the class and configuration. All the classes are under org.ew.bonder.device and i'm not sure if i have to add any annotation for DeviceRepository class.

## root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Have Spring servlet handle all static content -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ew.bonder.device"/>
```

## DeviceServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class DeviceServiceImpl extends BaseService implements DeviceService{
    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceService.class);
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DeviceServiceImpl(Validator validator, final DeviceRepository deviceRepository) {
        super(validator);
        this.deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public DeviceApi saveDevice(DeviceApi deviceApi) {

        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public DeviceApi createDevice(DeviceApi deviceApi) {
         LOG.info("Validating device request.");    
         validate(deviceApi);
         Device device = new Device(deviceApi);
         deviceRepository.save(device);
         return null;
    }

}
```

## DeviceRepository.java

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends MongoRepository<Device, String>  {

    @Query("select d from Device d where ownerid = ?")
    DeviceApi findByOwnerid(String ownerid);

}
```

## Error

```
Jul 24, 2015 2:02:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceServiceImpl' defined in file [/xxxx/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/ew/bonder/device/DeviceServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.ew.bonder.device.DeviceRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.ew.bonder.device.DeviceRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.ew.bonder.device.DeviceRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.ew.bonder.device.DeviceRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this implementation, but I know in another Spring implementation you need to define a Repository configuration that will scan packages for your interfaces so they know to create proxy implementations for it.  I think if you figure out how to do this it will inject properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add [@EnableMongoRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html) to a configuration class, or in your case use the XML equivalent: `<mongo:repositories base-package="base.pkg.for.repositories" />`